# Twitter modal positioning

Tags: grails, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap plugin for Grails and I'm having trouble centering modals. When I remove the class="modal" part from the div that contains the modal, my centering function works properly, but when I put it back (which is necessary for it to have the functionality of a modal it gets stuck halfway off the page). Any help would be very nice :D
Here's my code:

```
<a style="position: relative; top: 2px;" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal${instanceType.id}"
         id="${instanceType.id}"> ${message} </a>
<div class="modal" style="background: black; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; border: 2px solid white; float: center; position: absolute"
        id="myModal${instanceType.id}">
                <div style="border:none" class="modal-header">

                <a style="color:white;" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
        </div>
        <iframe id="iFrame" style="border: none;"width=800px height=675px src="${action}/${instanceType.id}">

        </iframe>
        <div class="modal-body" style="background: black;"></div>
        <div style="border:none; background: black;" class="modal-footer">
                <a "="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>

</div>
<script>
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
$(myModal${instanceType.id}).css({
    'width' : $(window).width()*.75,
    'height' : $(window).height()*.75
    })
$(myModal${instanceType.id}).center()

$('#modal-footer').append('<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="submitFunction()">${saveName}</a>')
function submitFunction(){
        $("iFrame").contents().find("#submit").click()
}
function changePre(){
        $("iFrame").contents().find(".buttonNew").submit()
        alert('hi')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap modals center themselves.  Why are you trying to do it manually?

Comment: Dude, I tried it without attempting to center it and it positioned itself oddly as well. It seems to center only the top and bottom positioning, but the left and right positioning automatically overlaps, and if I put it at for instance 0px it ends up being halfway off the page on the left side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the default modal styling centers the modal by absolute positioning. So when you customize a modal windows, and you change the size of it, you shall adjust relevant elements also. Like the modal-body and modal header and the .modal class.

And to answer your question, and if I got your question right, that is you were trying to position your modal VERTICALLY.

Open bootstrap.css , then find and edit .modal.fade.in

The default value is 50%. Try to play with it until you achieve your desired position. Increase it to move the modal to the bottom, decrease it and it will do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Default modal size modal window positions Horizontal centre of the screen, once the modal customizes(width changes), need to position it with script.

sample script:

$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true
}).css({
    width: '800',// custom width
    'margin-left': function () {
        return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
});